# Create metalsmith collection directly from array via Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, static-site, metalsmith

I'm generating a static site using Metalsmith's JavaScript API and `metalsmith-collections`. I have a custom build script which assembles an array `dogs` which I'd like to use to create a new collection.

```
const Metalsmith       = require('metalsmith')
const collections      = require('metalsmith-collections')
const layouts          = require('metalsmith-layouts')

var dogs = [
  { name: 'Rover' },
  { name: 'Dog' },
  { name: 'Daisy' }
]

Metalsmith(__dirname)
  .metadata({})
  .source('./src')
  .destination('./build')
  .clean(true)
  .use(layouts())
  .use(collections({
    dogs: {
      // ?
    }
  })
  .build((error) => {
    if (error) throw error
    console.log('All done!')
  })
```

There are no files for `dogs`; it's just an array which I've created myself. How do I instruct `metalsmith-collections` to create a collection from the array?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `metalsmith-collections` before, but looking at the docs [here](https://github.com/segmentio/metalsmith-collections) it looks like the tool is used to gather collections of files, not take an array of data as you are trying to do here.

The options object you pass to `collections()` should have a key for each collection you want (e.g. `dogs`), and each of those keys should be an object with options you want: `pattern`, which is a glob pattern for picking up what files should go into the collection (seems like this might be the only required option—the others seem optional), `sortBy`, which is a string that you can sort those files by that seems to pull from their metadata, `reverse`, which is a boolean you can use to reverse the sort, along with `metadata`, `limit`, `refer`, and a few others mentioned in those docs.

To apply this to your use case, I might suggest making a `dogs/` directory in the same location as the configuration file you've shared here, then putting, say, `rover.md`, `dog.md`, and `daisy.md` inside the `dogs/` directory. Then you should be table to do something like this:

```
  // ...
  .use(collections({
    dogs: {
      pattern: 'dogs/*.md'
    }
  }))
```

Then those Markdown (`*.md`) files in the `dogs/` directory should be present in your `dogs` collection.